# How to get the id in PDF page in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I've just recently started using TCPDF ,
the out put page i shown and the table headings are shown and also work the query but the the get id is NULL why?

iam pass a id  by url like

```
<h4><a href="pdf_1.php?$h_id=<?php echo $id;?>">Conver PDF</a></h4>
```

the id show in url but 
i var_dump the h_id that show NULL

**my pdf_1 page**

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,td,th{border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
 include_once '../connect.php';
 require_once('Pdf.php');
 function runQuery($query) {
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $resultset[] = $row;
  }  
  if(!empty($resultset))
   return $resultset;
 }
$h_id=$_GET['h_id'];  
$pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
  $pdf->SetTitle('Orders Report');
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
  $pdf->SetTopMargin(20);
  $pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
  $pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
  $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
  $pdf->AddPage();
$product_array =runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_invoic_details LEFT JOIN  tbl_sudent_bill ON  tbl_sudent_bill.stu_bill_id=tbl_invoic_details.bill_id Where tbl_sudent_bill. hostel_id='$h_id'"); 
$html1 ='<table>
       <tr>     
      <th>Serial no</th>
      <th>Roll_no</th>
      <th>Total Amount</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Reference_no</th>
       </tr>
       </table>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html1, true, false, true, false, '');
if (!empty($product_array)) { 
$i=1;
  foreach($product_array as $key=>$row){
$html = '<table>
     <tr>
      <td>'.$i++.'</td>
      <td>'.$product_array[$key]['roll_no'].'</td>
      <td>'.$product_array[$key]['total_amnt'].'</td>
      <td>'.$product_array[$key]['date'].'</td>
      <td>'.$product_array[$key]['reference_no'].'</td>
     </tr>
      </table>
';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 
 }} 
ob_end_clean(); 
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('pdf_1.php');
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

how to get the  h_id in my page please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: `<h4><a href="pdf_1.php?h_id=<?php echo $id;?>">Conver PDF</a></h4>` (remove `$` char)

Comment: thankz  @Autista_z   it's working

Answer (score 0):

passing id in url like

```
<h4><a href="pdf_1.php?h_id=<?php echo $id;?>">Conver PDF</a></h4>
```

i will remove '$' from h_id